# not break mid word in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make text in label without breaking mid-word. 
For example, I don't want work break like this. 
In case of "Best of the test"

```
"Best of th
e test"
```

or

```
"Best of the te
st"
```

I just break this words as follows:

```
"Best of 
 the test"
```

or

```
"Best of the
 test"
```

How can I do this? 
My codes are as follows:

```
- (NSArray *)stringsFromText:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableArray *characterArray = [self arrayOfCharactersInString:string];
    NSMutableArray *slicedString = [NSMutableArray array];

    while (characterArray.count != 0) {
        NSString *line = @"";
        NSMutableIndexSet *charsToRemove = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

        for (int i = 0; i < [characterArray count]; i++) {
            NSString *character = [characterArray objectAtIndex:i];
            CGFloat stringWidth = [[line stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", character] sizeWithFont:self.font].width;

            if (stringWidth <= (self.frame.size.width - 10)) {
                line = [line stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", character];
                [charsToRemove addIndex:i];
            } else {
                if (line.length == 0) {
                    line = [line stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", character];
                    [charsToRemove addIndex:i];
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        [slicedString addObject:[line stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];
        [characterArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:charsToRemove];
    }

    if (self.lineBreakMode == UILineBreakModeWordWrap) {
        slicedString = [self stringsWithWordsWrappedFromArray:slicedString];
    }

    return slicedString;
}
```

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing all of your own word wrapping? `UILabel` can do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;`